# Encrypt a file before being copied

Tags: windows, usb, flash-memory, windows-permissions

I am working on a program that will prevent data theft.

I want to encrypt every file that is being copied to an external drive before it is actually copied using a symmetric encryption.

Is it possible to do such thing on Windows?
Which encryption do you recommend to encrypt files? I am thinking AES128 on CBC mode.

Comment: Why you think you can't do that in Windows? Use AES-256 with CBC

Comment: @Freedo Thank you. maybe the windows API doesn't allow file copying interception but I guess this is not related to this network.

Comment: Why not simple use an encrypted drive , i.e. EFS, truecrypt or similar ?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich my target is to create a program that will work for everyone. Without changing their drive.

Comment: @HackinGuy: Truecrypt does not change the drive, it just offers an encrypted volume inside a file.